# Swagger does not validate enum query parameter

Tags: node.js, swagger, swagger-2.0

I'm using swagger 2.0 to define my API. I'm using enums as described in the docs [here](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/enums/). I have the following endpoint in my swagger.yml file:

```
/my-endpoint:
    x-swagger-router-controller: my-controller
    get:
      summary: my test endpoint
      parameters:
        - name: feeling
          in: query
          type: string
          enum:
            - happy
            - sad
          required: true
      produces:
        - application/json
      responses:
        200:
          description: OK
```

I would expect a `400 bad request` to be returned to the client if the `feeling` query parameter is not either `happy` or `sad`, but it accepts any string. Does swagger not validate that the parameter is in the enum?

Comment: What server framework are you using - [swagger-node](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-node), [swagger-tools](https://github.com/apigee-127/swagger-tools), something else?

Comment: Using swagger-tools